# apt-get install firefox package has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux, firefox, vmware

Using `apt-get install firefox` I get:
`Package firefox is not available but is referred to by another package`. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source 
E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate.

I have already tried `apt-get update` which did add more packages, but I am still getting the same error.

I can manually go onto firefox through the desktop Firefox ES icon and webpages work fine just not through the terminal. The firefox on my desktop is 52.6.0 but I need this upgraded to the latest for a script to run and need to run through terminal not just desktop. Not sure if the desktop firefox even has anything to do with my terminal at this point.

Using VMware player for kali Linux i386 32-bit

Answer (score 6):

Kali Linux ships with Firefox Extended Support Release or `firefox-esr`. According to the [Kali Linux Package Tracker](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/firefox-esr), `firefox-esr 52.6.0esr-2` is the latest version of Firefox available for Kali Linux. It appears you have the latest version of Firefox for Kali Linux installed. However what you are probably asking is that you want to install the newest Firefox release, Firefox Quantum or Firefox 57+.

[Here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux) is a guide to manually installing the latest version of Firefox on Linux. Make sure you have [all of the required dependencies met](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/58.0.2/system-requirements/) before following the steps listed in the [guide](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux).

If you want to manage your Firefox install via your package manager then you can follow this [guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-firefox-quantum-on-debian-stretch-linux) to add Debian Sid to your sources list and install the latest version of Firefox via apt. There are [risks](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) of course, but I am sure you can handle any issue that arises. Good luck!